# How to use Embed Tomcat create websocket server without annotation?

Tags: tomcat, websocket, http-status-code-404, embed

`https://github.com/ZTW1995/tomcat-websocket-demo`
Why can't the front-end connect to Tomcat's websocket when running the program according to the code of this repository.
I now know that there is a bug with a websocket address in chat. html, but I was unable to connect to the websocket even after testing with the Postman tool. Is this embedded Tomcat approach to building websockets incorrect?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.